# Namespacing forces my class to be unfound

Tags: php, namespaces

```
namespace foo; 

class foo{

}
```

`$foo = new foo();`

If I removed the namespace, the class works just fine, if the namespace is there, I get `class foo unfound` error. What is the reason for this?

Comment: That's the point of namespacing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is namespaced, then you need to reference that namespace when instantiating (assuming you're in the global namespace when you instantiate).

```
$foo = new foo\foo();
```

That's the whole point. You can have multiple `foo` classes in different namespaces.

```
namespace foo;
class foo {}
```

And then...

```
namespace bar;
class foo {}
```

And now...

```
$foo1 = new foo\foo();
$foo2 = new bar\foo();
```

Read up on how namespaces work: https://www.php.net/namespaces

Comment: Why must I put that new slash when instanciating the object? Isn't it possible to just use `new foo()`?

Comment: @ANW The whole point of namespacing is to separate your classes so that you don't get naming conflicts (among other things). See my updated answer. Namespaces allow you to have multiple `foo` classes, which means you _have_ to reference the namespace or else PHP doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: Well, the problem now is that when I use your method, other classes in my class, which are native to PHP can not be found. for example, I have the `new ArrayIterator()` and now I get error like ` Fatal error: Class' foo\ArrayIterator not found ` How do I then solve this problem

Comment: Once you start using namespaces, you need to be mindful of them throughout your code. Inside your `foo\foo` class, you are _inside_ that namespace. If you try to now access `ArrayIterator` it assume `foo\ArrayIterator` because that's the namespace you are in. To access a non-namespaced (really a global namespace) class do `\ArrayIterator`.

Comment: That is what I did. but I get this error `Call to undefined function ArrayIterator `

Comment: Umm. Is `ArrayIterator` a function or a class? Sounds like you're doing `$x = \ArrayIterator()` and not `$x = new \ArrayIterator()`